# How to iterate an array of objects, accumulate a property and update another property(a Total) of each item without using two for statement?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, iteration, .net-2.0

Having a model something like this (I cannot change this):

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I need to iterate an array of SomeObject to populate some values **and accumulate (perform not simple calculations) another fields**.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<SomeObject> myCollection = new List<SomeObject>()
    {
        new SomeObject() { Amount = 3 },
        new SomeObject() { Amount = 6 },
        new SomeObject() { Amount = 9 }
    };

    int totalAccumulated = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        PopulateAndCalculate(myCollection[i], ref totalAccumulated);
    }

    //I don't want to create here a second for to iterate again all myCollection to set his TotalAmount property. 
    //There is another way?

    Console.WriteLine($"The total accumulated is: {totalAccumulated}");
}

private static void PopulateAndCalculate(SomeObject prmObject, ref int accumulatedTotal)
{
    //Populate a lot of another fields
    accumulatedTotal += prmObject.Amount;
    prmObject.TotalAmount = accumulatedTotal; //This don't work, but I need something alike
}
```

I don't want a second for statement to update `TotalAmount` property of each item in `myCollection`.
The main requirement is iterate the whole array, few times, don't care about string interpolation this is a short demo, this code must run in .net 2.0.

Theres is a clean/better way?

Comment: @TimSchmelter because it is updating TotalAmount with the accumulatedTotal value of each iteration, and the final accumulatedTotal value is assigned only to the TotalAmount of the last object in the array.

Comment: You *have to* re-iterate the whole list. On first iteration you calculate the aggregated value, on the second one you set the property for every instance. Even using LINQ - which is what I think you´re after - this stays the same, LINQ simply hides those iterations from you.

Comment: Are you saying you would like `TotalAmount` to be `18` in this example for all 3 elements of `myCollection`?

Comment: I think I get what you're going for?  Would it be correct to say that TotalAmount should contain the sum of the calculations executed on all three objects, and that Amount should hold the calculated values for only that instance of the object?

Comment: @petelids yes, but I need to find a way to avoid the second for statement.

Comment: You need another loop because you don't know the total amount until you have enumerated all items. Then you want to set this property with the calculated total-value for every object, so you need another loop. This would work if you could change `SomeObject` to contain a reference type for `TotalAmount` and all objects share the same instance.

Comment: What exactly is your problem on a second loop? It´s exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @TimSchmelter maybe I can fire an event inside every SomeObject from outside to update his TotalAmount?

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter and HimBromBeere; you will need the second loop unless you change your class design (the class design seems a little off here IMHO).

Comment: @HimBromBeere one of my requirements says don't iterate two times the same array.

Comment: @petelids I can add properties, delegates to this class but I can't remove.

Comment: Who makes such requirements? This is pure nonsense.

Comment: True, the class design is broken because a single object should not know anything about the total amount of other objects. You should implement a collection type that holds `IEnumerable<SomeObject>` and stores this value.

Comment: Are you able to modify the existing properties?  If so, all you need to make this work is to add "static" to TotalAmount's modifiers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter the class design is like that, because it will be used as a xml datasource in a report that group the whole info.

Comment: That means *every* instance knows its own `Amount` and the `TotalAmount` of all instances that exist in an arbitrary list? Really weird design.

Comment: The only potential way is to pass some shared class instance holding the total to each object constructor and use explicit property getter/setters.

Comment: why don't you just use Linq? it will be single expression I guess. Also remove 'ref' parameter and just return value from your `PopulateAndCalculate` method

Comment: @a-man "Why not use Linq?" Because - as I already told - it just hides its iteration to the outside. However it will also iterate the original array twice. Moreover OP can´t use Linq on .NET 2.0

Comment: your solution with pattern is very good

Comment: Your requirement is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually simple, though it's not exactly a good coding practice. 
What you really need is for `TotalAmount` to be a `static` property. Without that, there's this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<SomeObject> myCollection = new List<SomeObject>()
    {
        new SomeObject() { Amount = 3 },
        new SomeObject() { Amount = 6 },
        new SomeObject() { Amount = 9 }
    };

    int totalAccumulated = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        PopulateAndCalculate(myCollection[i], ref totalAccumulated);
    }

     /*****This is the new part*******/
    myCollection[0].TotalAmount = totalAccumulated;
    myCollection[1].TotalAmount = totalAccumulated;
    myCollection[2].TotalAmount = totalAccumulated;

    Console.WriteLine($"The total accumulated is: {totalAccumulated}");
}
private static void PopulateAndCalculate(SomeObject prmObject, ref int accumulatedTotal)
{
    //Populate a lot of another fields
    accumulatedTotal += prmObject.Amount;
   //no need to mess with the total here as far as the properties are concerned.

}
```

Comment: Your new part is still basically iterating over the array.

Comment: Yes, just not with a loop.  I keep coming back to this question to see if I can improve on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can st fields inside linq expression.
Could you consider this please

```
myCollection.ForEach(c => c.TotalAmount = myCollection.Sum(a => a.Amount));
Console.WriteLine($"Total accumulated :{myCollection.First().TotalAmount}");
```

Comment: Linq isn't available.  The application is in .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the **Observer Pattern**.

Firstly I created a global delegate to be used by an event:

```
public delegate void UpdateTotalAmountDelegate(int totalAmount);
```

Then a new class called: 'CalculatorSetter'

```
public class CalculatorSetter
{
    public event UpdateTotalAmountDelegate UpdateTotalAmounthHandler;

    public void UpdateTotalAmount(int prmTotalAmount)
    {
        UpdateTotalAmounthHandler(prmTotalAmount);
    }
}
```

I refactor the data object 'SomeObject' adding a field of type CalculatorSetter.

```
public class SomeObject
{
    private CalculatorSetter finalCalculator;

    public void SetCalculator(CalculatorSetter prmCalculator)
    {
        this.finalCalculator = prmCalculator;
        finalCalculator.UpdateTotalAmounthHandler += FinalCalculator_UpdateTotalAmounthHandler;
    }

    private void FinalCalculator_UpdateTotalAmounthHandler(int totalAmount)
    {
        this.TotalAmount = totalAmount;
    }

    //Some Other Fields
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

And my original code and **unique for**:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<SomeObject> myCollection = new List<SomeObject>()
    {
        new SomeObject() { Amount = 3 },
        new SomeObject() { Amount = 6 },
        new SomeObject() { Amount = 9 }
    };

    CalculatorSetter commonCalculator = new CalculatorSetter();

    int totalToAccumulate = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        PopulateAndCalculate(myCollection[i], commonCalculator, ref totalToAccumulate);
    }
    commonCalculator.UpdateTotalAmount(totalToAccumulate);

    Console.WriteLine($"The total accumulated is: {totalToAccumulate}");
    Console.WriteLine($"The first total accumulated is: {myCollection[0].TotalAmount}");
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: So you replaced one loop with another list **and** loop (you know that += operator on event creates invocation list and `UpdateTotalAmounthHandler(prmTotalAmount)` iterates the list and calls each delegate, right?). This is the worst possible implementation.

Comment: Your solution now loops 2xNumber of elements. So with 3 elements you will loop 6 times. Great solution.

Comment: @IvanStoev it's rigth, it iterates the list of delegates and not the list of SomeObject, why the worst?

Comment: @JohnG the first time I iterate an array of a heavy SomeObject and the second time I iterate a List of delegates, a delegate with a precise task. I do not loop two times the array of 'SomeObject'.

Comment: With 3 items and using your (non working/incomplete code) You are looping 6 times. 2 times for each added item.

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper and keep it simple (if you want you can change a little for use static methods you can, or static class but I dont see the point)
the result is:

- The Amount is 3, The total ammount is 18
- The Amount is 6, The total ammount is 18
- The Amount is 9, The total ammount is 18

  ```
   namespace Prueba1
  {
  class Program
  {
  public class WrapperInt {
      public int Value { get; set; }
  }
  public class SomeObject
  {
      public int Amount { get; set; }
      public WrapperInt TotalAmount { get; set; }

  }

  public Program() {

      WrapperInt TotalAmountAllArrays = new WrapperInt();
      List<SomeObject> myCollection = new List<SomeObject>()
         {
          new SomeObject() { Amount = 3, TotalAmount =TotalAmountAllArrays  },
          new SomeObject() { Amount = 6 , TotalAmount =TotalAmountAllArrays },
          new SomeObject() { Amount = 9 , TotalAmount =TotalAmountAllArrays }
          };

      for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++)
      {
          myCollection[i].TotalAmount.Value += myCollection[i].Amount;
      }
      foreach (var c in myCollection)
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"The Amount is:" + c.Amount + "  The total ammount is:" + c.TotalAmount.Value);   
      }

  }
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      new Program();
  }


   }
     }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work for you… One possible solution is to create a wrapper class called `MyTotalList` which contains a `List` named `amounts` and an `int` named `total`. `MyTotalList` class does not expose its list `amounts` as an editable list. If the class exposes this list as editable, then other methods could ultimately change an items value in that list and the `MyTotalList` class would not be aware of this and unfortunately contain an incorrect `total`. To avoid this situation and for the class to work as expected, methods must use the `MyTotalList`’s `Add` and `Remove` methods. To ensure this happens, the private List `amounts` in the `MyTotalList` class returns a read only list which ensures that changes to the list will not be made outside the `MyTotalList` class. Leaving the list exposed and editable will/could cause the class to contain an incorrect `total`.

My solution is to create a Class that wraps a `List`. `MyTotalList` class has a no argument constructor. Once a new instance of a `MyTotalList` object is created you can then use that instance to `Add` `MyObject` items to its list. Every time an item is added to the `MyTotalList`, list `amounts` the variable `total` gets updated with the added item’s `amount`. Example:

Create a new `MyTotalList` object:

```
MyTotalList listOfObjects = new MyTotalList();
```

Then add some `MyObject` instances to the `listOfObjects`

```
listOfObjects.Add(new MyObject(1,3));
listOfObjects.Add(new MyObject(2,6));
listOfObjects.Add(new MyObject(3,9));
```

After you add the items, you can then use the `listOfObjects` `Total` property to get the total sum of all `MyObject` items in the list with:

```
listOfObjects.Total
```

If you need to pass or use the `List` of `MyTotalList` items you can use:

```
listOfObjects.Items
```

Bear in mind as I discussed above, this `List` `Items` is a read-only list. Therefore you cannot add/remove items in this list as you would an editable list. So the code below will fail during implementation as these methods are not exposed for read only objects.

```
listOfObjects.Items.Remove(new MyObject(4, 10)); 
listOfObjects.Items.Add(new MyObject(4, 10));
```

The above lines will cause the compiler to complain: xxx… does not contain a definition for Add/Remove. This ensures methods will use the `MyTotalList.Add` and `MyTotalsList.Remove` methods and eliminate any possibility of the list changing outside the `MyTotalList` class.

MyObject Class

```
class MyObject : IComparable {
  public int id { get; }  
  public int amount { get; }

  public MyObject(int inID, int inAmount) {
    id = inID;
     amount = inAmount;
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return amount.ToString();
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return id.GetHashCode();
  }

  public override bool Equals(object other) {
    if (other != null)
      return (this.id == ((MyObject)other).id);
    return false;
  }

  public int CompareTo(object other) {
    if (this.id > ((MyObject)other).id)
      return 1;
    if (this.id < ((MyObject)other).id)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

MyTotalList Class

```
class MyTotalList {
  private int total;
  private List<MyObject> amounts;

  public MyTotalList() {
    total = 0;
    amounts = new List<MyObject>();
  }

  public int ListCount {
    get { return amounts.Count; }
  }

  public IReadOnlyCollection<MyObject> Items {
    get { return amounts.AsReadOnly(); }
  }

  public int Total {
    get { return total; }
  }

  public void Add(MyObject other) {
    if (other != null) {
      if (!(amounts.Contains(other))) {
        total += other.amount;
        amounts.Add(other);
      }
      else {
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate id's not allowed!");
      }
    }
  }
  public void Remove(MyObject other) {
    if (amounts.Contains(other)) {
      total -= amounts[amounts.IndexOf(other)].amount;
      amounts.Remove(other);
    }
    else {
      Console.WriteLine("Item to remove not found!");
    }
  }
}
```

Examples

```
MyTotalList listOfObjects = new MyTotalList();
listOfObjects.Add(new MyObject(1,3));
listOfObjects.Add(new MyObject(2,6));
listOfObjects.Add(new MyObject(3,9));

Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Initial list with total");
Console.WriteLine("items in list:");
foreach (MyObject mo in listOfObjects.Items)
  Console.Write(mo.ToString() + " ");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Total from list of " + listOfObjects.ListCount +
                  " items is: " + listOfObjects.Total);

Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Add three more items");
listOfObjects.Add(new MyObject(4, 10));
listOfObjects.Add(new MyObject(5, 11));
listOfObjects.Add(new MyObject(6, 12));
Console.WriteLine("items in list:");
foreach (MyObject mo in listOfObjects.Items)
  Console.Write(mo.ToString() + " ");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Total from list of " + listOfObjects.ListCount +
                  " items is: " + listOfObjects.Total);

Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("Remove id 4 (10) from the list");
listOfObjects.Remove(new MyObject(4, 10));
Console.WriteLine("items in list:");
foreach (MyObject mo in listOfObjects.Items)
  Console.Write(mo.ToString() + " ");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("Total from list of " + listOfObjects.ListCount +
                  " items is: " + listOfObjects.Total);
```

**A Side note to your original post…About the class you can not change**

```
SomeObject {
  public int Amount { get; set; }
  public int TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Regardless of how you get the total for the`int` varable: `TotaAmount`… for each instance of `SomeObject` class to contain the same variable with the same amount and you want to ensure this is true for all existing `SomeObject` instances… is well a poor design. This creates redundant data and simply waste space and it makes no sense for each variable to contain this value as it has absolutely nothing to do with that `SomeObject` instance. This class design is counter intuitive of a good design. As @Tim Schmelter’s comment points out *"a single object should not know anything about the total amount of other objects."* This “redundant data” situation is something a programmer should try to avoid, not promote.